# Add number of products for category

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to add field to categories contain number of products associated with this category
my code is

```
exports.paginate = async (Model,page,limit,sort,populate) => {
     const Product = require('../models/product')
     const count = await Model.countDocuments()
     const pages = Math.ceil(count/limit)
     const skip = (page - 1) * limit
     let data = await Model
     .find()
     .populate(populate)

     .limit(parseInt(limit))
     .skip(parseInt(skip))
     .sort(sort)
     let data2 = data.map(  (item) => {
          item.set('productCount', Product.find().countDocuments(),{strict:false});
          return item

     })
     return {
          data2,
          pages,
          totalItems:count,
          lastPage:pages,
          nextPage:parseInt(page)+1
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I fount the solution

```
let data2 = await Promise.all( data.map( async (item) => {
          item.set('productCount', await Product.find({categories:item._id}).countDocuments()  ,{strict:false});
          return item

     }))
```